# Use if/else within textfield?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I have already found several ways to use `if` / `else` tags and also [how to use it within a `<tr>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14683387/2471882).

But is it possible to use it within a `<s:textfield>` tag ?

I want to disable several fields (textfields and datepicker) if a certain parameter is true. At the moment, I have the whole code twice. Once with `disable="true"`and once without. This makes the jsp extremely verbose.

I would be very happy if there were a better/shorter way.

Comment: What do you need, to hide them, to not put them in page, what ?

Comment: I want to disable the fields if a certain condition is true to make further edits impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this expression inside `<s:textfield>`

```
disabled="%{myCondition}"
```

where `myCondition` should evaluate to `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for!

In my case, I have an object that actually is `TRUE`or `FALSE`. Whould it theoretically be also possible to have a different statment as a condition? saying `disable=%{varialbe==0}"`? Would that work too?

Answer (score 4):

There are many solutions to this problem, each one fitting it better according to the number of tags, the cleanest/shortest code ratio desired, etc...

For example, you can

1. set a variable and use it in your textfields:

   ```xml
   <s:set var="disabled" value="%{condition}"/>
   <s:textfield ... disabled="%{#disabled}" />
   ```
2. use an action method that returns a boolean, as in @PredragMaric answer:

   ```java
   public boolean getConditionFromAction(){
       return (foo!=bar);
   }
   ```

   ```xml
   <s:textfield ... disabled="%{conditionFromAction}" />
   ```
3. create two JSP snippets and include them (overkill in case of just disabled, but helpful in other cases, like showing a complete different set of fields)

   ```xml
   <s:if test="%{condition}">
       <s:include page="snippetA.jsp" />
   </s:if>
   <s:else>
       <s:include page="snippetB.jsp" />
   </s:else>
   ```

   (in which case, remember to put

   ```xml
   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
   ```

   in the snippets too).
4. disabling them with javascript on page loading (example with jQuery):

   ```
   <script>
       $(function(){
           <s:if test="%{condition}">
               $("input[type='text']").attr('disabled','disabled');
           </s:if>
           <s:else>
               $("input[type='text']").removeAttr('disabled');
           </s:else>
       });
   </script>
   ```

   (better using a class selector ovbiously).

Regarding your latest comment:

> I want to disable the fields if a certain condition is true to make further edits impossible.

remember that you [**MUST perform the controls server side**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341208/1654265), because every user is able to alter the HTML / DOM (with Firebug, or FF DevTools, Chrome DevTools etc...) or simply forging a request *ad-hoc* without even visiting your page, and enabling the fields you have disabled.

Client side validation is user friendly and appreciated as a first filter, server side one is mandatory.